# Alamofire and Pre-signed url upload object

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, swift3, alamofire

currently I'm trying to upload an image by using Alamofire, the example implementation from Amazon is the following: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

the .NET version code:

```
private void UploadS3FileByPresignedUrl(string url, string localFile, string contentType)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(localFile))
            {
                //// Need to add contentType otherwise the StreamContent is "binary/octet-stream"
                var fileContent = new StreamContent(stream);
                fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);
                var response = client.PutAsync(url, fileContent).Result;
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }

        }
    }
```

Basically I have to upload the image with 2 conditions:

- Only support jpg image file.
- After client get the upload URL, need to use the HTTP PUT with the  content-type "image/jpeg" to upload the profile image Here is a example code for .NET client

I'm trying to do this by using Alamofire but I have been unsuccessful...

I'm using swift 3 with Alamofire 4, currently I have this code:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "Sky-Sunset")

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:{ multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.5)!, withName: "photo_path", fileName: "swift_file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")},
                         usingThreshold:UInt64.init(),
                         to:".../my/profile/image/uploadurl",
                         method:.put,
                         headers:["Content-Type": "image/jpeg"],
                         encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                            switch encodingResult {
                            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                                upload.responseJSON { response in
                                    debugPrint(response)
                                }
                            case .failure(let encodingError):
                                print(encodingError)
                            }
        })
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using AWS SDK for iOS , For pre-signed url support you can follow the documentation @ https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3-pre-signed-urls.html

```
AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder.default().getPreSignedURL(getPreSignedURLRequest).continueWith { (task:AWSTask<NSURL>) -> Any? in
    if let error = task.error as? NSError {
        print("Error: \(error)")
        return nil
    }

    let presignedURL = task.result
    print("Download presignedURL is: \(presignedURL)")

    Alamofire.upload(
       multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
             multipartFormData.append(unicornImageURL, withName: "unicorn")
             multipartFormData.append(rainbowImageURL, withName: "rainbow")
       },
       to:presignedURL.absoluteString
       ...
    return nil
}
```